# Dataframe not showing after conditional statment

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a program where I have to type c to show a month's calendar, and p to show a picture, the conditional statement works fine when I press p, but when I press c the program just finishes without displaying anything.

```
days= {'Sunday': [' ','4','11','18','25'],
       'Monday': [' ','5','12','19','26'],
       'Tuesday': ['','6','13','20','27'],
       'Wednesday' : [' ','7','14','21','28'],
       'Thursday': ['1','8','15','22','29'],
       'Friday' : ['2','9','16','23','30'],
       'Saturday' : ['3','10','17','24','31']}
        
capt={
    'selector': 'caption',
    'props': 'margin:20 px;text-align:center;color:black; font-size: 15px; font-weight:bold'}

bol={
    'selector': 'td',
    'props': 'text-align: center; font-weight: bold;'
}
calendar = pd.DataFrame(days).style.hide(axis='index').set_caption("January 2004").set_table_styles([capt,bol])

def redd(v, props=''):
    if v=='30':
        return props
```

---- this is the code of the dataframe, it displays correctly outside a conditional statement.

req = input("Please type 'F' if you want to see a picture \nPlease type 'C' if you want to see a month's calendar\nInput:")

```
if req.lower() in ['c']: 
    calendar
elif req.lower() in ['p']:
    io.imshow(picture)
else:
    sys.exit("Invalid Input, closing program")
```

when I type c, nothing happens. The program works correctly when I type p or any other letter

Comment: should it be print(calendar) ?

Comment: it does not work as well

Comment: tried req.lower()=="c" instead of in ['c'], just curious why it is put as in 'c'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're running the program on a Jupyter notebook, I think you would need to call [IPython.display.display](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.display) function to display `Styler` object

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display


days= {'Sunday': [' ','4','11','18','25'],
       'Monday': [' ','5','12','19','26'],
       'Tuesday': ['','6','13','20','27'],
       'Wednesday' : [' ','7','14','21','28'],
       'Thursday': ['1','8','15','22','29'],
       'Friday' : ['2','9','16','23','30'],
       'Saturday' : ['3','10','17','24','31']}

capt={
    'selector': 'caption',
    'props': 'margin:20 px;text-align:center;color:black; font-size: 15px; font-weight:bold'}

bol={
    'selector': 'td',
    'props': 'text-align: center; font-weight: bold;'
}
calendar = pd.DataFrame(days).style.hide(axis='index').set_caption("January 2004").set_table_styles([capt,bol])

def redd(v, props=''):
    if v=='30':
        return props

req = input("Please type 'F' if you want to see a picture \nPlease type 'C' if you want to see a month's calendar\nInput:")

if req.lower() in ['c']: 
    display(calendar)
elif req.lower() in ['p']:
    io.imshow(picture)
else:
    sys.exit("Invalid Input, closing program")
```